# Is this possible to add count number to select box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-controls, custom-component

I have a select box like this

```
<select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}"
        onchange="this.size=0;" onblur="this.size=0;" style="width:200px">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
</select>
```

When clicked the arrow to drop the list, it only show first five options. Now I want to achieve this - when I scroll down, a number will appear near the scrollbar which is same as the current selected option (like when I scroll to 6th option, that number will show "6", when I scroll to 10th option it will show "10" and so on). Any ideas on how to do this?

An image for demo as shown below

[image]

Comment: If I got it correctly you want to show the value from the <option></option> near the scrollbar. Is that correct ?

Comment: Have you check [onchanged](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) method of `<select>` tag? You can set the scrollbar value in this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of glitch is there.. would work on it later.. in hurry now.. but you get the basic idea..

**UPDATE**

Completely working example.

So the logic goes like this, the current bottom element's position number is calculated by adding the no of elements in view port `displaySize` and the no of scrolled up elements from bottom.
So the height of last scrolled up element from bottom which has now came into view port is derived from dividing the current `scrollTop` by height of `option` element.

```js
$(function(){

  var $select = $('#customSelect')
  var $counter = $('#counter')
  var displaySize = 5
  var optionEleHeight
  
  $counter.text(displaySize)
  
  $select.scroll(function(e){
 
    optionEleHeight = optionEleHeight || this[0].offsetHeight
    currentBottomEleNo = this.size +
                               Math.round(e.currentTarget.scrollTop/optionEleHeight)
  
    $counter.text(currentBottomEleNo)

  })
  .on('change blur', function(){
    this.size=0
    $counter.hide()
  })
  .on('mousedown', function(){
    if(this.options.length>displaySize){
       this.size=displaySize
       $counter.fadeIn()
    }
  })


})
```

```css
.selectContainer{
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
}
#customSelect{
  width:200px;
}
#counter {
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  top: -40px;
  float: right;
  color: #1CD1D8;
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=selectContainer>
  <select id="customSelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
</select>
<div id=counter></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, thank you a lot, try and search for this for hours before give up and come here to ask; and i will more grateful if you can explain your script (i'm still new with java) like why division for 16 - i think 15 better, it will make the count show 15 when scroll to bottom not 14 like when division for 16

Comment: and @vinayakj , can you please do this with normal select (the one have auto vertical scroll when it have >20 options, and explain about the division number too)

Comment: @HenryVarro Please find the updated answer for all your queries

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/v4vishnuprasad/pm1ck4bd/1/)

I changed HTML to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<select id="input1" name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange="this.size=0;" onblur="this.size=0;" style="width:200px">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
    </select>
    <div id="total_count_preview"></div>
    <div id="selected_count_preview"></div>
```

And jquery

```
$('#input1').on("change",function() {

    $("#total_count_preview").text('Total '+$("#input1 option").length + " items");
    $("#selected_count_preview").text('Selected Item  '+this.selectedIndex);
});
```

Is that you need?